# Using a Jquery plugin twice on a page

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have installed a JQuery date picker plugin. I have two dates that need to be picked.

```
  <div class="col-md-5">
    From:  <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    To:   <input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" >
  </div>
```

I have then called them in between script tags with

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

This seems to work but I am wondering whether there is a neater way to do this regarding the way I have written the two lines above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `.col-md-5` will always contain your datepicker `input`s:

```
$('.col-md-5 input').datetimepicker();
```

Or even better; give your `input`s a unique class, and use that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    From:  <input class="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    To:   <input class="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker2" type="text" >
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use comma separated multiple selector.Try this:

```
 $('#datetimepicker,#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the plugin supports multiple selectors, but you can try supplying two selectors to the plugin:

```
$('#datetimepicker, #datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

This same method *is* supported by jQuery as mentioned [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.

---

Another example would be to hide multiple elements at once:

```
$('#elem1, #elem2').hide();
```

---

In these instances one should consider using a class name to "group" elements together. One should use the `id` attribute when one and only one element is being dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=datetimepicker]').datetimepicker();
```

But even better would be using a common class name for them and use like this:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: Using code like this would be an indication that you should use class names instead of the `id` attribute.

Comment: @Lix what problem with id?

Comment: There is no problem but selecting multiple `id`'s just feels to me like a mistake. If there are multiple elements that need to be handled together, it would make much more sense to give them the same classname and use that instead.